# copy camera image buffer to gstreamer buffer

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing a gstreamer plugin similar to v4l2src that captures live video from our camera and display using gstreamer.

My plugin is able to sucesfully generate a yuv file.

Now I need to copy camera image buffer to gstreamer buffer and push it to the next element. For this I used the below method:

```
    GstBuffer  *outbuf1

    outbuf1 =  gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL,*buflen,NULL);
    ret_size = gst_buffer_fill(outbuf1,pImgBuf->pBuffer[0],pImgBuf->iFilledLen[0]);

    ret = gst_pad_push(Video->gst_filter->srcpad,outbuf1);
```

Here I get the error code `GST_FLOW_FLUSHING`

Further debugging this I also generated one yuv file from the data in image buffer before copying image buffer to gstreamer buffer:

```
    fwrite( pImgBuf->pBuffer[0], pImgBuf->iFilledLen[0], 1, Video->File );
```

This yuv file is sucesfully generated and played using vooya.

Now when I try to generate the yuv file using the gstreamer buffer yuv file is not properly generated as it is not played on vooya and gives the error message "no good data"

Here is my code flow for more details:

```
static void gst_imx219src_init (Gstimx219src * filter)
{
    printf("================================Inside  gst_imx219src_init============== \n");
  filter->sinkpad = gst_pad_new_from_static_template (&sink_factory, "sink");
  gst_pad_set_event_function (filter->sinkpad,
                              GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR(gst_imx219src_sink_event));


-----------------code for camera init and recording -------------------

  ret = start_processing_on_event_dequeue( hHandle, filter );


start_processing_on_event_dequeue : This function will start the recording process in camera.This function internally calls the below function:


void Video_DeliverInput( void *hVideo, CAM_ImageBuffer *pImgBuf , CAM_StreamID  strmId)
{

    VideoChain *Video = (VideoChain*)Video;
    CAM_Error         error  = CAM_ERROR_NONE;
    int retCode = *buflen;
    GstBuffer  *outbuf1,*outbuf2,*outbuf3;

    GstFlowReturn ret;

    buflen = pImgBuf->iFilledLen;
    outbuf1 =  gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL,*buflen,NULL);
    outbuf2 =  gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL,*buflen,NULL);
    outbuf3 =  gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL,*buflen,NULL);
    gst_buffer_memset(outbuf1, 0, '\0', *buflen);
    gst_buffer_memset(outbuf2, 0, '\0', *buflen);
    gst_buffer_memset(outbuf3, 0, '\0', *buflen);

    if ( Video->iEncoderType == 0 ) // yuv
        {
            if ( Video->File != NULL )
            {
                fwrite( pImgBuf->pBuffer[0], pImgBuf->iFilledLen[0], 1, Video->File );
                fwrite( pImgBuf->pBuffer[1], pImgBuf->iFilledLen[1], 1, Video->File );
                fwrite( pImgBuf->pBuffer[2], pImgBuf->iFilledLen[2], 1, Video->File );
            }
        }

        if(outbuf1)
        {

        ret_size = gst_buffer_fill (outbuf1, 0, pImgBuf->pBuffer[0],pImgBuf->iFilledLen[0]);
        ret_size = gst_buffer_fill (outbuf2, 0, pImgBuf->pBuffer[1],pImgBuf->iFilledLen[1]);
        ret_size = gst_buffer_fill (outbuf3, 0, pImgBuf->pBuffer[2],pImgBuf->iFilledLen[2]);
        }

            else
            {
                printf("===========failed to create buffer \n");
            }


        gst_pad_set_active (Video->gst_filter->srcpad,TRUE);
        ret = gst_pad_is_active (Video->gst_filter->srcpad);
        ret = gst_pad_push(Video->gst_filter->srcpad,outbuf1);
#if defined( PLATFORM_PROCESSOR_ULC )
        if(strmId == CAM_STREAM1)
        error = CAM_PortEnqueueBuffer( hVideo->hCameraEngine, CAM_PORT_PREVIEW, pImgBuf );
        else
            error = CAM_PortEnqueueBuffer( hVideo->hCameraEngine, CAM_PORT_STILL, pImgBuf );

        ASSERT_CAM_ERROR( error );
#else
        error = CAM_PortEnqueueBuffer( hVideo->hCameraEngine, CAM_PORT_VIDEO, pImgBuf );
        ASSERT_CAM_ERROR( error );
#endif
    //}

     return;
}

  filter->srcpad = gst_pad_new_from_static_template (&src_factory, "src");
  ret = start_processing_on_event_dequeue( hHandle, filter );
```

Please can anyone help me with this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What pipeline are you using to test this and what application are you running this pipeline on?
And are you inheriting from some base class? In which function of this baseclass you do the gst_pad_push?

Comment: I use the pipeline : gst-launch-1.0 imx219src ! video/x-raw, framerate=25/1, width=1280, height=720 ! ximagesink

Comment: What about the other question about the base class? Did you try using GST_DEBUG?

Comment: Hi, please find the details in my post I have edited the post.Yes I tried using GST_DEBUG but i did not get much details about the issue.